# traverse dom to find $(.more) of div that contains class .disable

Tags: jquery

I have this dom tree:

```
<li class="badge_listtwo">
    <div class="badge_spacetwo">
        <p class="badge_title">$badge_title</p>
        <div class="badge_button">
            <img src="badgeImages/sample.png" />
            <a href="#" id="$badge_id" class="more">More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="badge_button">
        <a href="#" class="disable">Disable</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

I was wondering how, using jquery, I can get the "id" of .more based on finding which `<li>` contains the .disable class (how would I traverse it efficiently is what Im asking because I'm trying to store this id in var badge_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a single element, this will do:

```
var badge_id = $('li.disable .more').attr('id');
```

If you need an `array` of the ids, this is the solution:

```
var badge_ids = $('li.disable .more').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

---

If you are looking for the `a` elements' id with the class `more` inside a `li` which has an `a` element with the class `disable`, then this would be the selector:

```
var badge_id = $('li:has("a.disable")').find('a.more').attr('id');
```

Comment: I think this would select if the li class = disable...not wether an element (a in this case) contains class = disable

Comment: @PraneetSharma Are you looking for `a` elements that have both `more` and `disable` classes? Or the `a` elements with the class `more` inside a `li` which has an `a` element with the class `disable`? I added a second part to my answer for the second solution.

Comment: @Shef read the HTML... it is an li that _contains_ both .more and .disable elements

Answer (score 1):

If `<li class="badge_listtwo">` is always the parent you could do

```
var test = $('.disable').closest('li.badge_listtwo').find('.more').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var badge_id = $("li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(".disable").length;
}).first().find(".more").attr("id");
```

You can also use the ":has" selector as Shef suggests.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can be a good idea for performance

```
var lifinder = $('li').find('a.more')
var badge_id = lifinder.attr('id');

if (badge_id != undefined) {
alert(badge_id);
}
else {

alert('not found');  
}
```